# HTTP Basic Authorization on IP Camera using AJAX / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, authentication

I understand that this question was asked plenty of times before but it seems that none of the responses worked for me so here's my issue:

I have a Sony IP camera that is in the intranet. I am building a site with PHP/MySQL authentication for internal users to be able to view the MJPEG stream but the camera itself requires http authentication. I do not want to have the users enter their username and password to log into the camera page and then have to type the http authentication credentials (in the popup) to see the stream. I tried using jQUERY to change the headers to no avail. Keep in mind that the camera MUST have its own authentication so that users cannot just randomly type the IP and see the stream. I want to be able to control who views what and when.

I am assuming that if I make a correct authentication call when the user logs into the page, that camera will be available to them since they would have "silently" logged in. Also, if I use wget from the terminal with the --headers: "Authorization: blah_Blah" it actually works but I can't do this from jQuery! Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://some_ip_internally_for_the_cam/some_page_on_cam_that_needs_authentication_to_access_otherwise",
    method : 'GET',
    beforeSend : function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "some_base_64_stuff_that_works_in_wget");
    },
    success: function() {
       $("div.log").attr("innerHTML", "ok");
    }
});
```

This gets loaded as soon as the user logs in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show an exaple of "some_base_64_stuff_that_works_in_wget".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: When it comes to the same origin policy for firefox, wouldn't that mean that it will work on IE?

Comment: An example of base 64 that works in wget is: "YWRtaW46YtRtaW3="

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Javascript error in Firefox:

> ... 0x804b000f (NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader] ...

As I was trying to set a new HTTP header in some [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

The error occured because I was trying to set the HTTP header **before** the XMLHttpRequest.open() method.

Source:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4542.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that `div.log` doesn’t display the “ok” message, it’s probably because your DOM code is incorrect. This:

```
$("div.log").attr("innerHTML", "ok");
```

sets a DOM attribute of the `div`, not its actual `innerHTML`. Instead, you should do:

```
$("div.log").html("ok");
```

Comment: Using innerHTML is usually bad programming. This time is one of those. Use what the DOM spec has and everything will be ok. You don't need to use innerHTML.

Comment: No the end result is that the authentication window still pops up. Even if I remove the part of the code that has to do with the div.log. I also get the following error in Firefox: 

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b000f (NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]"  nsresult: "0x804b000f (NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://hide_my_address/ :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 35"  data: no]

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the div. Forget the div please. I am focusing on the ajax request. I deleted the code that changes the div's html. The issue is that it is not authenticating the user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the username and password fields in .ajax?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain/mypage.php",
    username: "myUsername",
    password: "myPassword",
    error: function () {
    }
}).done(function(html) {
        //Do Stuff
});
```

This works for me in a similar scenario.